# Working with a subset of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe with 50 columns and 100,000,000 rows. While working with smaller chunks of data at a time, I apply a series of functions (including row drops) to a subset of the same three columns of the dataframe.

Would the other 47 columns of the dataframe slow this down? If so, I'm thinking about making a copy of the dataframe at the beginning with just those three columns, applying the functions, and then joining them with the 47 other columns. I'm not sure if Python processes each of the 50 columns in each function, though, so I don't know if this is necessary.

Thank you!

Comment: Pandas makes copies of data frames by default. Normally there's an option for "inplace" and that will preserve memory at the cost of processing time.

Comment: copies are always the right way to go, which is what that is the default for pandas